# How to generate samples from MVN model?

Tags: r, montecarlo, multivariate-testing

I am trying to run some code on R based on this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612857v1) through example 5.1. I want to simulate the following:

[image]

My background on R isn't great so I have the following code below, how can I generate a histogram and samples from this?

```
xseq<-seq(0, 100, 1)  
n<-100
Z<- pnorm(xseq,0,1)
U<- pbern(xseq, 0.4, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
Beta <- (-1)^U*(4*log(n)/(sqrt(n)) + abs(Z))
```

Comment: You can simulate multivariate normal distributions with mvrnorm from the MASS package. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/mvrnorm.html

Comment: @jandraor Thanks, but how can i alter the coefficients as above?

Comment: For simulating univariate random normal samples, you should use rnorm, instead of pnorm. In the case of Bernoulli distribution, you can simulate it with rbinom with n =1. Look at the mvrnorm documentation for the generation of samples. You need to specify means and a covariance matrix.

Comment: Can you tell us anything about your desired covariance matrix of your variables in the $X_i$ collection? (For instance, are they supposed to be i.i.d. standard normal variables?)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery, Generated i.i.d. by standard multivariate normal, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some demonstrations of tools that will be of use:

```
rnorm(1)                 # generates one standard normal variable
rnorm(10)                # generates 10 standard normal variables
rnorm(1, 5, 6)           # generates 1 normal variable with mu = 5, sigma = 6
                         # not needed for this problem, but perhaps worth saying anyway

rbinom(5, 1, 0.4)        # generates 5 Bernoulli variables that are 1 w/ prob. 0.4
```

So, to generate one instance of a beta:

```
n <- 100                 # using the value you gave; I have no idea what n means here
u <- rbinom(1, 1, 0.4)   # make one Bernoulli variable
z <- rnorm(1)            # make one standard normal variable
beta <- (-1)^u * (4 * log(n) / sqrt(n) + abs(z))
```

But now, you'd like to do this many times for a Monte Carlo simulation. One way you might do this is by building a function, having `beta` be its output, and using the `replicate()` function, like this:

```
n <- 100                    # putting this here because I assume it doesn't change
genbeta <- function(){      # output of this function will be one copy of beta
  u <- rbinom(1, 1, 0.4)
  z <- rnorm(1)
  return((-1)^u * (4 * log(n) / sqrt(n) + abs(z)))
}

# note that we don't need to store beta anywhere directly; 
# rather, it is just the return()ed value of the function we defined

betadraws <- replicate(5000, genbeta())
hist(betadraws)
```

This will have the effect of making 5000 copies of your beta variable and putting them in a histogram.

There are other ways to do this -- for instance, one might just make a big matrix of the random variables and work directly with it -- but I thought this would be the clearest approach for starting out.

---

**EDIT**: I realized that I ignored the second equation entirely, which you probably didn't want.

We've now made a vector of `beta` values, and you can control the length of the vector in the first parameter of the `replicate()` function above. I'll leave it as 5000 in my continued example below.

To get random samples of the Y vector, you could use something like:

```
x <- replicate(5000, rnorm(17))     
  # makes a 17 x 5000 matrix of independent standard normal variables
epsilon <- rnorm(17)
  # vector of 17 standard normals
y <- x %*% betadraws + epsilon
  # y is now a 17 x 1 matrix (morally equivalent to a vector of length 17)
```

and if you wanted to get many of these, you could wrap *that* inside another function and `replicate()` it.

Alternatively, if you didn't want the Y vector, but just a single Y_i component:

```
x <- rnorm(5000)    
  # x is a vector of 5000 iid standard normal variables 
epsilon <- rnorm(1)
  # epsilon_i is a single standard normal variable
y <- t(x) %*% betadraws + epsilon
  # t() is the transpose function; y is now a 1 x 1 matrix
```